# I want to make a for loop, but it won't compile

Tags: android, for-loop, sudoku

```
for(sudoku.get((int)(0)).doubleValue(); == sudoku.get((int)(1)).doubleValue();) {  
    sudoku.remove((int)(1)); 
    Sudoku.add(Double.valueOf(SketchwareUtil.get random((int)(1)), 
((int)(9))));  
}
```

The error wants me to remove the "==" in the condition.
This is the first time I have tried to use "for" for something that isn't a repeat a set amount of time.

Comment: since you're just using the condition part of the for loop you could just use a while loop instead. I would recommend reading about the different types of loops available in Java - they are pretty standard across similar programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is small typo mistake in semicolon :

```
for(; sudoku.get((int)(0)).doubleValue() == sudoku.get((int)(1)).doubleValue();) {  
    sudoku.remove((int)(1)); 
    Sudoku.add(Double.valueOf(SketchwareUtil.get random((int)(1)), 
((int)(9))));  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Would the semicolon always go first in situations like this?

Comment: I advice you to read this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loops-in-java/ , it will help you to understand loops better